# Cakephp - Automagic select box not being created

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the following code in my controller

```
$technicians = $this->Customer->Technician->find('list');
$account_managers = $this->Customer->Account_Manager->find('list');
$this->set(compact('technicians','account_managers'));
```

I have the following code in my User model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'TicketComment' => array(
        'className' => 'TicketComment',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'CustomerTech' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'technician'
    ),
    'CustomerManager' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'account_manager'
    )
);
```

I have the following code in my customer model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Technician' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'technician',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Account_Manager' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'account_manager',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

And I have the following code in my view

```
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $this->Form->label('technician', 'Technician', array('class' => 'control-label'));?>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('technician', array('class' => 'span12')); ?>
    </div><!-- .controls -->
</div><!-- .control-group -->

<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $this->Form->label('account_manager', 'Account Manager', array('class' => 'control-label'));?>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('account_manager', array('class' => 'span12')); ?>
    </div><!-- .controls -->
</div><!-- .control-group -->
```

"Technician" is showing up as a proper automagic select box in my view, but "Account_Manager" is showing up as a simple text input box. As far as I can tell, the two are setup identically. So why is the second input not forming a select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, its AccountManager (no _) for the Model's name.

```
$accountmanagers = $this->Customer->Account_Manager->find('list');
$this->set(compact('technicians','account_managers'));
```

You cant say $var and pass down $other and expect $var to be available in the view :)

So it should (logically) read:

```
$accountManagers = $this->Customer->AccountManager->find('list');
$this->set(compact('technicians','accountManagers'));
```

Also note the camelBacked attribute casing.

And it will still only show up if you got a field called "account_manager_id" (which you should according to conventions when referring to other field's primary keys).

Comment: I had a typo the controller code I posted. I have now corrected it. My code actually had $account_managers as the variable name.

Comment: Also, Account_Manager is not a model, but an alias for an association as you can see in my model code above. My Customer table has a field named account_manager that is a foreign key to the Users table. Does that help?

Comment: It's also not valid for aliases. They need to have the same proper naming scheme (CamelCaseStyle). If you dont follow conventions (field named account_manager) then you need to manually tell the form helper here that you are taking the options from the $accountManagers array.

Comment: I modified the alias, controller and view. My controller now has $accountManagers = $this->Customer->AccountManager->find('list');
$this->set(compact('technicians','accountManagers'));

I am referencing that in the view and it works correctly. I get the select box I was looking for! However, when I save a new customer, the Account Manager is not saving. Is there anything I need to do in the controller before the save?